# Why do I get double binary size when I instantiate a static object inside a free function in C++?

Tags: c++, gcc, embedded, size, static-variables

On an embedded system (Cortex-M4) I write C++ that compiles with GCC `arm-none-eabi-g++`. Compiler version  `10.2.1 20201103`.

My code is kind of complicated to copy paste it here, so here's an example:
I have a class that abstracts a hardware peripheral.

```
class A
{
public:
    void init(void)
    {
        // initializes hardware peripheral
    }
    // other public functions here
private:
   int x,y;
   // other private variables here
};
```

I want to use this class to use it inside an RTOS task.
in `a.cpp` file I have a free function `myDriver_init` that is linked with `extern "C"` keyword.
The free function `myDriver_init` creates an RTOS task and gives it a callback to run.

```
extern "C" myDriver_init(void)
{
    static A a;
    create_RTOS_task(&myDriver_state_machine, &a, priority, stack_size);
}

void myDriver_state_machine(void * param)
{
    A * a_ptr = static_cast<A*>(param);
    a_ptr->init();
    while(true)
    {
        //user code here...
    }
}
```

In `main.c` I call the C linked function like this

```
int main(void)
{
    myDriver_init();
    ...
    RTOS_Task_run();
}
```

The question is why do I get almost double size of binary when the object `a` is inside the functon `myDriver_init`?

If I move it outside and use it as a global variable the size of the binary goes significantly smaller.

```
static A a;
extern "C" myDriver_init(void)
{
    create_RTOS_task(&myDriver_state_machine, NULL, priority, stack_size);
}

void myDriver_state_machine(void * param)
{
    a.init();
    while(true)
    {
        //user code here...
    }
}
```

Why is this happening?

The optimization I use is `-O2` in both cases.

I thought static variables/objects within functions are placed in the heap. What's the difference here?

I see some `std::bad_exception` in the map file of the big binary. Despite having `-fno-rtti` and `-fno-exceptions` flags.

Comment: If you generate linker map files for each binary, what are the differences between the memory maps?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude How can I tell the difference? There's a difference in module's size though.

Comment: To begin with, just check for differences using `diff` or similar program?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I use `winmerge`, yes there are many...

Comment: "_I thought static variables/objects within functions are placed in the heap._": They typically placed either with their value in the `.data` section or if zero-initialized into the `.bss` section without including the binary data itself. (I don't know anything about your platform though.) The same as global variables.

Comment: If your class cannot be constant-initialized, then initialization of a local static variable is more complicated because it is guaranteed to be thread-safe and exception-safe. (For example if the initialization throws an exception and you call the function again later, it has to try again. Similarly if you have multiple threads calling the function synchronization between them has to be guaranteed.) But if your class can be default-constructed as a constant expression that shouldn't apply.

Comment: You can try to avoid that by adding `constinit` before the declaration (assuming C++20) and then adjusting the class until it can be constant-initialized and the compiler accepts the `constinit`.

Comment: By the way, why can't `a` be defined as a simple and normal local variable inside the `myDriver_state_machine` function? Is the stack on your target system extremely limited, and will `a` be too large to fit om the stack?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I don't want it to place it in the stack. It's big enough I think...

Comment: What are you comparing? The true binary size, or the .o object module size? They are not the same thing.  Exactly how are you making this observation and drawing this conclusion?

Comment: @Clifford the `map` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that somehow the compiler produces more code into the final binary when you create static objects inside functions like my example in the question.
That piece of code has something to do with exceptions which is not a desirable result in my case.

Changing the linker flags from

```
-specs=nosys.specs
```

to

```
-specs=nano.specs
```

solves the problem.