# Why does "nano.specs" includes exceptions despite having fno-exception flag?

Tags: c++, exception

Following my previous [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73232965/why-do-i-get-double-binary-size-when-i-initialize-a-static-object-inside-a-free).

When I initialize an instance of a class inside a free function the binary gets exploded in size. I get almost the double size.

```
void my_function(void)
{
    static MyClass obj;
    createTask(callback, &obj, stack_size task_prio);
}
```

I saw in the map file that there are some exception added.
Like...

```
std::bad_exception::what() const  
std::bad_exception::~bad_exception()
std::exception::what() const
std::get_unexpected()
std::exception::~exception()
std::get_terminate()
std::terminate()
std::set_unexpected(void (*)())
```

Despite having the flag `-fno-exceptions` in my compile flags in `cmake` I see that data above in my `map` file.

If I move the `static MyClass obj;` line outside of the `my_function` The code size remains normal and very small.

I was experimenting with the linker flags and I changed `-specs=nosys.specs` to `-specs=nano.specs` and now the code size is exactly the same. I checked the `map` file again and no exception added.

Why did that happen?

System: Cortex-M4
Language: C and C++
Compiler: GCC

Comment: When the object is at block scope the compiler has to worry about exception handling.  When it is in global space that's not needed as you can't catch exceptions on global variables.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you for the comment. Why is that? Why does the compiler still add exception despite having included the flag `-fno-exceptions` though? And what does it have to do with `-specs.` flag?

Comment: Not sure about that.  Just explaining why the scope can change the exception handling.